# Can I consider interface methods as abstract methods?

Tags: object-oriented-design, interfaces, abstract-class

I was thinking about that, and I had some doubts.

When I declare an interface, for example:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
   public void method1();
   public void method2();
}
```

Could these interface methods be considered abstract? What I mean is that the concept of an abstract method is:

> An abstract method is a method that is declared, but contains no implementation.

So, could these methods be considered abstract? They are not "pure" abstract methods as I'm not using the `abstract` word, but conceptually, it looks like they are.

What can you tell me about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably best on SO

Comment: @billy.bob - I think it's too abstract for Stack Overflow. There's not a *specific* coding issue here.

Comment: Is this Java code?

Comment: no it's not. it's just an example. the question is not focused on any programming languages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An interface is like a "purely" abstract class.  The class and *all* of its methods are abstract.  An abstract class can have implemented methods but the class itself cannot be instantiated (useful for inheritance and following DRY).

For an interface, since there isn't any implementation at all they are useful for their purpose: a contract.  If you implement the Interface then you *must*   implement the methods in the interface.

So the difference is an abstract class can have implemented methods whereas a interface cannot.

The reason they are separate is so a class can implement several interfaces.  Java and C# restrict a class to inherent from a single parent class. Some languages allow you to inherit from multiple classes and you could accomplish the work of an interface via a "purely" abstract class.  But multiple inheritance has its problems, namely the dreaded [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)

Comment: +1 for incorporating the difference between inheritance of an abstract class and implementation of one or more interfaces.

Comment: Diamond Problem is an awesome paradox.

Comment: I dissagree with 'An interface is like a "purely' abstract class" part. They are 2 different types of OO 'building blocks', so they are really not similar at all. They share some common features, but in nature they are different types, more like men and women for example :)

Comment: @Emmand Kareem I do not dissagree with 'An interface is like a "purely" abstract class' part.  That's why i wrote it :-).  If you have any good reasons for your disagreement please post, id like to hear

Comment: It's worth noting that c#8 also introduces the concept of a [default interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45912519/2791540)

Answer (score 11):

I found an usefull answer here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

> All of the methods in an interface are implicitly abstract, so the
>   abstract modifier is not used with interface methods (it could be—it's
>   just not necessary).

Comment: Also note that an abstract class extends _one_ other object.  Interfaces have no notion of a superclass.

Comment: Also note that you can implement multiple interfaces, but you can only inherit from one class, abstract or not.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: An interface can extend one or more interfaces. It isn't the same things as a super class, but it is a level of inheritance.

Comment: You can implement multiple interfaces. Looks like the concept of multiple inheritance, but not exactly.

Comment: @unholysampler, which is not a superclass - as I said.

Answer (score 4):

Abstract classes **can** have abstract methods.

Interfaces **can only** have abstract methods.

`method1()` and `method2()` in your example are abstract methods.

Answer (score -1):

The difference here is that abstract classes can contain implementation details, although cannot be instantiated by themselves.  Whereas an interface is merely a template for a class

Comment: Abstract **methods** cannot contain implementation details.  Abstract **classes** can.

Comment: I know the difference between a method and a class - but I can't understand the point you're making?

Comment: Your answer states that abstract methods can contain implementation details - they can't.  Just a typo?

Comment: I fixed the typo.

Comment: @billy.bob this question is about the abstact method though.

Answer (score -2):

So in a subclass, inherited abstract method can again go abstract without implementation , while if a class implements an interface it's method  must be implemented.

Answer (score -3):

Interface classes don't have abstract methods. They don't have any methods at all. They just have a list of methods that another class would have to implement to be able to conform to the interface. In your example, there is no method method1 and no method method2 until someone adds these methods to a class.